# reverse string to pattern matching

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, pattern-recognition, string-matching

I have a list of patterns, and I need to find the pattern that matches an input string the most. I.e.:

Patterns:

```
[
    'AB1XXX',
    'AB2XXX',
    'ABXXXX-0080',
    'BC1XXX',
    'BC15XX'
]
```

The `X` character in the patterns is reserved as the `wildcard` or `don't care` character. It can be any single alphanumeric character.

I then get an input, i.e.: `AB1100`. In this case I expect the pattern `AB1XXX` to be the best match.
However, if I get an input `AB1100-0080` I expect `ABXXXX-0080` to be the best match for the given input.

I currently use a Trie to find the matching pattern, but it doesn't really work for the given example as it either can't find a match once it gets to `-0080`.

`Best match` can be seen as "shortest Levenshtein distance with the least amount of **X** characters used".

Is there a known algorithm I could implement or should I stick to implementing a Levenshtein distance algorithm?

Comment: Does `X` mean *any character*? Do *the most* and *best* mean *with the shortest Levenshtein distance*?

Comment: @reinierpost yes, sorry, X is the wildcard, so it can be any character. "the most" or  "best" would mean "with the shortest levenshtein distance and with the least `X`s" I'll edit my post in a minute to clear it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Shortest Levenshtein's Distance should be good enough.
See if this [Matching Wildcards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_wildcards) Wikipedia page can be of help.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up expanding my Trie implementation with a full-search which returns all matches. Then I added a levenshtein function to find the "best" match out of the matches that the Trie retuned..